# Can't intersperse " " and unwords be used as drop in replacements for each other?

Tags: haskell, blaze-html

I was trying to rewrite:

```
return $ renderHtml $ mconcat $ intersperse " " $ catMaybes links
```

Which works just fine, into:

```
return $ renderHtml $ mconcat $ unwords $ catMaybes links
```

but it is returning:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Char’
               with ‘blaze-markup-0.7.0.2:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()’
Expected type: H.Html
  Actual type: Char
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘mconcat $ unwords $ catMaybes links’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘renderHtml $ mconcat $ unwords $ catMaybes links’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  return $ renderHtml $ mconcat $ unwords $ catMaybes links
```

I'm not the greatest with Haskell yet, but I thought `intersperse " "` and `unwords` where just drop in replacements for one another?

**Edit**:  Ultimately, I'd like to figure out a way to use `unwords`... Figuring out why it's giving me the error and how I can work around it is the goal! =)

Comment: They are of different types. `mconcat . intersperse " "` together are `unwords`.

Comment: @n.m. Or just `concat . Intersperse " "`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `unwords :: [String] -> String` function only works on lists of `String`s. What you have is a list of values of type `MarkupM ()`.

The reason why `intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]` works is that it works of list on any type. With `OverloadedStrings` pragma the `" "` value has type `MarkupM` (because that type has an instance for `IsString`). The `intersperse` function takes a list of these markup values and puts spaces in between them but still returns a list of markup values. Finally `mconcat` joins the list into a single value still of type `MarkupM ()`. With some pseudo data constructor you can imagine the values like this:

```
[Markup "foo", Markup "bar", Markup "baz"] -- returned by catMaybes links
[Markup "foo", Markup " ", Markup "bar", Markup " ", Markup "baz"] -- after intersperse
Markup "foo bar baz" -- after mconcat
```

There is no easy way to get `unwords` to work in this case as you don't have strings and converting to strings would lose you some benefits. Having the markup encapsulated in appropriate wrapper makes sure that you do not produce not well-formed HTML, for example.

Answer (score 2):

What you have will work if you use `LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings`.

Otherwise, use `intersperse (text " ")` instead of `intersperse " "`.

E.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.Blaze.Html
import Text.Blaze.Renderer.String
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import Data.Monoid

foo links = renderHtml $ mconcat $ intersperse " " $ catMaybes links
```

Comment: I'm using `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` and I still can't use unwords.  I mean, it's working fine using `intersperse " "` but I feel that there has to be a way to write it otherwise.